# XGboost Algorithm: Passing a variable that is not a regressor

Tags: python, python-2.7, xgboost

I wanted to run an XGBoost algorithm on a dataset, how do I tell the algorithm that the unique ID column in the data is not a regressor.

Currently I have passed the data like below:-

```
modelfit(xgb1, DAT[DAT.columns.difference(['id'])], Y)
```

And then I later join the predicted labels to the data.But I was wondering if python changes the indexing using the model building process. If this were true, it would mean, when I join the data I would be mapping the wrong ID with the predicted labels.

Hope I am making sense!

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to pass the columns except id. What do you want to do after that? I am sorry but I am not able to understand.

Answer (score 0):

At model building/testing time the order of features corresponds to the order of output. So you need not to worry about because it maintains the order